# Regex (Python) data extraction - overlapping or incomplete results

Tags: regex

I'm trying to extract data from some WHO codebooks that I've converted from PDF to text with Python slate library.

The text I want to hit starts with 2 digits, dash, 2 digits, followed by some text and ends with "Q"+1 or 2 digits and again "Q"+1 or 2 digits

```
17-17How old are you?Q1Q1
31-31During the past 30 days, how many times per day did you usually eat fruit, such as bananas, apples, oranges, dates, or any other fruits?Q7Q11
```

Sometimes those phrases end with a blank, sometimes the next questions starts immediately (here are three question), observe Q4Q424-29 and Q5Q530-30

```
20-23How tall are you without your shoes on? (Note: Data are in meters.)Q4Q424-29How much do you weigh without your shoes on? (Note: Data are in kilograms.)Q5Q530-30During the past 30 days, how often did you go hungry because there was not enough food in your home?Q6Q7
```

With

```
\d{2}-\d{2}[a-zA-Z0-9 .()?:,]+Q\d{1,2}Q\d(\d)*?
```

I get pretty close, but I'm missing the second digit when the second "Q" has two digits.

I've tried to add a negative lookahead

```
\d{2}-\d{2}[a-zA-Z0-9 .()?:,]+Q\d{1,2}Q\d((\d)(?!\d\d-))
```

to exclude the start of the pattern with two digits and a dash.

```
\d{2}-\d{2}[a-zA-Z0-9 .()?:,]+Q\d{1,2}Q\d{1,2}
```

includes the second digit of the "Q" but generates overlapping results e.g. at Q4Q424-29 where the first string ends with Q4Q42 and the second string starts with 4-29.

The regex with parts of the original sample text is here: https://regex101.com/r/d9Dlga/2/

Any suggestions who to extract the correct strings like:

```
17-17How old are you?Q1Q1
20-23How tall are you without your shoes on? (Note: Data are in meters.)Q4Q4
24-29How much do you weigh without your shoes on? (Note: Data are in kilograms.)Q5Q5
31-31During the past 30 days, how many times per day did you usually eat fruit, such as bananas, apples, oranges, dates, or any other fruits?Q7Q11
```

Thanks!

Comment: Your lookahead based pattern was close, bot you need to check for a single following digit and make the whole thing optional, like `Q\d((\d)(?!\d-))?`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I see the problem now. New attempt that I think works:

`\d{2}-\d{2}.+?Q\d{1,2}Q\d{1,2}(?!\d-\d{2})`

I put a negative lookahead at the end to test if a new section has begun.

- 9 matches
- Correctly grabs the full 2-digit endings

[Demo](https://regex101.com/r/YQAIRl/2)

Comment: Thanks to both of you! Just made my evening!

Answer (score 0):

The following pattern should work:

`\d{2}-\d{2}[a-zA-Z0-9 .()?:,]+Q\d{1,2}Q\d(\d(?!\d-))?`

Comment: _should_? Does it or doesn't it? Could you please add an axplanation why the changes you made achieve OPs goal?

Comment: Depends on whether I understood OP's goal properly. It's identical to what you wrote in a comment some seconds before I posted my answer (but with useless parenthesis removed).

Comment: Well I personally think that your answer is correct, but I am not a huge fan of code-only answers - seems someone found this reason enough to dv your answer (wasn't me). See e.g. https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/148272/is-there-any-benefit-to-allowing-code-only-answers-while-blocking-code-only-ques